# ionic and cordova - css active not working on android device

Tags: android, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework with cordova platform. The css for active state of an element (div, button or a) works fine in browser during development/testing but not at all in android device/emulator

i have defined some classes

```
.bg-dark {
 background: #333333 !important;
}

.bg-active-darkBlue:active {
background: #16499a !important;
}
```

and following html

```
<a class="fg-white bg-active-darkBlue button" style="background-color:#3B5998;">Sign in with Facebook</a>
```

even tried this (got on ionic forum)

```
<a ng-mousedown="class='bg-active-darkBlue'" ng-mouseup="class='bg-dark'" menu-close class="fg-white {{class}}">Sign in with Facebook</a>
```

tried for a,div and button tags.
still not working on android, only works in browser, please help.

Answer (score 3):

By experience, angular `ng-mousedown` and`ng-mouseup` events do not fire up on the mobile device. My experience was ionic 1.6.4 on iOS.

However, on-touch and on-release works flawlessly well. So just replace `ng-mousedown` and `ng-mouseup` with `on-touch` and `on-release`, respectively.

`<a on-touch="class='bg-active-darkBlue'" on-release="class='bg-dark'" menu-close class="fg-white {{class}}">Sign in with Facebook</a>`

Here is the [pointer](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onTouch/) to the ionic reference documentation on the `on-touch` and `on-release` events.

Hope this helps..

Comment: hoo thank you @mcku that works very well for Ionic angularjs cordova android device

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the "right" way of doing this is according to 
[phonegap-tips.com](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/essential-phonegap-css-webkit-tap-highlight-color.html) is to add an `ontouchstart="return true;"` on the element.

eg.

```
<a class="bg-active-darkBlue" ontouchstart="return true;">:active now works in cordova</a>
```

That worked for me, so I hope it works for you too.