# Ionic App CSS style is not showing properly in android device after build

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, ionic-framework

I have an issue whith CSS, Ionic serve showing exactly what required but after the app built , the CSS is not applied ,i have added `class="platform-android"` with no luck, any help on this is very much appreciated.

**View Code**

```
<i ion-ripple ion-ripple-color="#ff0000"class="material-icons" style="font-size: 32px" ng-click="ChangeClass({{$index}}) ;" ng-class="{{$index}} ===selected && flag===false ?  class='favorite' : class='favorite_border'">       {{class}} </i>
```

**CSS**

```
.favorite_border { color: lightgrey;}.favorite {color: red;}
```

**JS Code**

```
$scope.temp=""
    var i =0 ;
    $scope.ChangeClass=function(p)
    {
      $scope.selected=p;
      $scope.flag=false;
      if (($scope.temp===$scope.selected)) 
      {
        ++i ;
        $scope.flag=true;
        if (i>1)
        {
           $scope.flag=false;
           i=0;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        $scope.flag=false;
        i=0;
       }

      $scope.temp=p;
    }
```

Comment: inline style works at least for the time being

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of ng-class is detailed here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

There are a few things about the code you provided:
- You can´t use {{}} inside javascript codding, you have to use $index as it is and maybe then turn it into a string.
- Tehre is no context for $index.
- ng-class needs a string, object or angular variable to work.

I didn't understand your intentions but if you want to change the colour and text inside the  on click you can use the following code:

```
<i ion-ripple ion-ripple-color="#ff0000"class="material-icons" style="font-size: 32px" ng-click="ChangeClass()" ng-class="class">{{class}}</i>
```

And inside your controller:

```
  $scope.class = 'favorite';
  $scope.ChangeClass = ChangeClass;

  function ChangeClass() {
    if ($scope.class === 'favorite') {
      $scope.class = 'favorite_border';
    } else {
      $scope.class = 'favorite';
    };
  }
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/tinchomm/pen/ggOoLy?editors=1111)

If you happen to be inside and ng-repeat and have an $index you can pass it to your ChangeClass($index), save the classes inside an array (for example) and then access it with that index.

Comment: the controller code i built before exactly the same of the code above and  I change later on  to achieve "icon change from "fav_border" to "fav" icon on icon itself click  , no issue with the code i have now in Js file , the issue i have now with the style , colors in the CSS file is applied when i run ionic serve but after i build the app "APK" , it seems the defualt colors "black" is applied not what i have in CSS, i am not able to understand why inline style works and ng-class style is not ?

Comment: i found this post may be i need to replace ng-click with touch events [using device events on-touch start and on touch end ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092592/ionic-and-cordova-css-active-not-working-on-android-device?rq=1)

Comment: But the ng-class and the code from the html won't work as you posted here.
Besides that, ionic works with ng-click as well as on-touch, so that's not it.
You can try adding **!important** to your css properties.

Comment: May be the issue with {{}} i used in HTML however the js file tested as posted  , i will update the code as you mentioned above and add !important to CSS .